# How to redirect with Web Api 2 IHttpActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have Register action which return IHttpActionResult

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register()
    {
        //some code;
        //Here I want after a successful registration, to redirect to the action /Token with parameters
        //Like this return Redirect("/Token",new {id = id, name = name}");
    }
```

how to redirect to `/Token`

Comment: user RedirectToRoute

Answer (score 0):

You simply decorate the action that the request comes into (or whole controller) with the `[authorize]` attribute.

That way, MVC will pass the request to the in-built authentication provider for authentication.

I wrote a blog about authentication with Web API which should have some good samples and background information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2015/03/25/securing-and-working-securely-with-web-api.aspx